# kb4012215 - Обновление не применимо к данному компьютеру!:(

Tags: windows-7, установка, обновление, wannacry

kb4012215 - Обновление не применимо к данному компьютеру!:(
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ноут ACER-5235, проверил автоматически через центр обновления Windows - kb4012215 нет. В ручную не хочет. Обновления устанавливаются автоматически. Не пойму в чем проблема.

Лог Установщика:

> ApplicabilityInfo="Windows 7.0 Client SP1;Windows 7.0 Embedded 
>   SP1;Windows 7.0 WinPE 3.1;" Applies to="Windows 6.1" Build Date="2017/03/04"
>   Company="Microsoft Corporation" File Version="1" Installation
>   Type="FULL" Installer Engine="Component Based Servicing - WUSA.exe"
>   Installer Version="6.0.0.0" KB Article Number="4012215" Language="ALL"
>   Package Type="Security Update" Processor Architecture="x86" Product
>   Name="Windows 6.1" Support
>   Link="http://support.microsoft.com?kbid=4012215"

---

Лицензия. Да остальные обновления устанавливаются без проблем. Я бы и не обратил если бы не WannaCry. Единственные изменения в системе это ручками проведенное лечение от шпионажа. Обновление не редактировал, оставил как есть.

Comment: Пиратская или лицензия?

Comment: Если с лицензионностью проблем нет, то либо обновление отозвано, либо перекрыто неким следующим.

Comment: Если обновления устанавливаются автоматически - значит вы получили патч еще в марте. Спите спокойно :)

Comment: Да я то спокойно к этому отношусь, не первый десяток лет за компом. Но предпочитаю понять/разобраться, в списке обновления нет, в чем проблема. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: У меня 4012212 установилось. А 4012215 не хочет.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего в системе уже присутствует обновление, которое заменило собой kb4012215. Я у себя к такому выводу пришел.

Comment: KB4015549 заменяет KB4012215

Comment: KB4019264 заменяет KB4015549

Comment: а что надо делать если среди установленных обновлений нет KB4015549 и КВ4019264

Comment: Сергей как вы и сказали на некоторых компах где выдавало ошибку Это обновление не применимо к этому компьютеру я удалил среди установленных обновлений КВ4019264 или КВ4005549 и это мне помогло установить КВ4012215. Но на одном комьютере нет ни КВ4015549 ни КВ4019264 но все равно выдает ту же ошибку